# Could anyone help me on solve an algorithm? (Set a weight of a big range value)

Tags: java, algorithm, range, decimal, weighted

I was wondering how to set a weight for a computation of huge different values. I will try to explain it better, or maybe in details.

The idea is:
I would like to have as a result a value in this range [1,20] given:
1) first value: a
1a) with a format like 0.1 or 0.0001 or 0.00001 etc.
1b) maximum decimal length = 5 decimals
2) second value: b
2a) assumption that is less than a (if a=0.01, at least b=0.00999 etc.)
2b) with the same format
2c) maximum decimal length = 6 decimals (so 1 grater than a)

where, given for example a=0.01 and b=0.0001

```
x = a/b = 100
```

a second example a=0.01 and b=0.00001

```
x = a/b = 1000
```

I thought at something like this:
If maximum could be (when a=0.1 and b=0.000001) = 100000 than it correspond to 20 (the new maximum scale)
and if I count the difference of number of decimals I can say that:
'a' has 1 decimal
'b' has 6 decimal
In general we can have a maximum difference of 5, so:

```
max = 5
```

So using this calculus:

```
diff=6-1=5
```

in order to correspond their fraction (a/b) as the maximum value (20) I can do:
`(diff*20)/max` give me 20. That's ok.
Now, If I have a=0.1 and b=0.000002
I can use the least significant number of 'b' (in this case '2' of 0.000002) and compare with the least significant of 'a', and I can say that

```
diff=6-1=5
```

Now subtract 0.2 (because the least significant number was 2) to have 4.8.
Now recompute:

```
4.8*20/max = 19.2
```

So for 0.1 and 0.000003 would be

```
diff=6-1=5
diff=diff-0.3 = 4.7
4.7*20/max = 18.8
```

And so on.

The problem is that when I have a=0.3 and b=0.0002 (for example) I don't know how to manage it.

Could anyone suggest me a solution or a bunch of that even with a pseudo-code or procedure?
Maybe I will do the translation in java by myself.

I don't know where to post my question, if so I really apologize if I wrong some rules of these website, otherwise everything is fine :-)
Thank you all

Comment: by far the worst explained question I have seen on StackOverflow for a while. what is `x` - your answer? Are you trying to clamp / scale `x` to fit the range?

Comment: I am not a native English speaker, I am not an expert in Math, I asked this question during the night, I am ill and I am not an expert in explain something that I not really have so clear. So, if you want to offend, ok feel free to do it, or if that question is a shame feel free to report my question to admin or moderators. If you prefer to criticize my question, I think that it would be more constructive if you point out every problem that I have. It's not simple to explain problems in an other language, so, sorry for that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at logarithms?

```
 d = (log(a) - log(b))/log(10)
```

should give the answer. In other words, log(a)/log(10) gives you

```
0.1   -->  -1
0.01  -->  -2
0.001 -->  -3
```

etc. So, you can calculate differences the way you want. And in the end,

```
exp(d*log(10))
```

is the actual ratio. In java, use `Math.log()`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. That's what I missed! The logs didn't arise in my mind, don't know why. Anyway I appreciate your help to my weird question. Now I can make up something better with your clarification. Thank you again, and sorry to you as well for bad explanation of my question/problem. I tick (or stick i don't know how to say) your answer as the right one.